# Github actions failing to recognise outputs of another job in an if/needs condition

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have set up a workflow with multiple jobs. Job A is a requirement for Job B to run.

The workflow is triggered on PR, and Job A checks for the existence of a comment on the PR:

```yaml
job-a:
    outputs:
      comment: ${{ steps.find-comment.outputs.comment }}
    steps:
    - name: Check if QR already exists
      uses: peter-evans/find-comment@v2
      id: find-comment
      with:
        issue-number: ${{ github.event.number }}
        comment-author: "github-actions[bot]"
        body-includes: Preview Bundle

    - name: Store find-comment output
      run: echo "comment=${{ steps.find-comment.outputs.comment-id }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

    - name: Check find-comment outcome
      run: echo "This is the output of find-comment ${{ steps.find-comment.outputs.comment-id }}" # Successfully logs out comment id
```

I set the output of the check into `comment` in `outputs` for that job.

In Job B, I then need to check if that output is an ID or an empty string:

```yaml
job-b:
    needs: [job-a]
    if: always() && needs.job-a.outputs.comment == ''
    steps:
      - name: Check for find-comment
        run: echo "This is the input of find-comment ${{ needs.job-a.outputs.comment }}" # always logs out an empty string
```

The `if` check always equates to true, i.e. the `outputs.comment` is always an empty string. I've tried multiple variations of the if check, with and without the `always()`, with and without the `[]`, but `needs.job-a.outputs.comment` always is an empty string even though it successfully logs out the comment id in the check in `job-a`. This job then always runs, which is not what I want. I only want the job to run when the PR comment doesn't exist.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to change the `outputs` variable to take `comment-id` instead of just `comment`. I thought the chained property had to match what you put int eh `echo` command, but apparently it has to match what is in the outputs of `peter-evans/find-comment@v2`: https://github.com/peter-evans/find-comment#outputs

```yaml
job-a:
    outputs:
      comment: ${{ steps.store-comment.outputs.comment-id }}
```

Comment: sure, in this way you don't need the extra step. My answer was about highlight was is required in order to make it works. I agree, this approach is better

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an identifier for the step in order to be able to refer it as an output for the job. See the relevant part of the [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter):

> Sets a step's output parameter. Note that the step will need an id to be defined to later retrieve the output value.

So you should change your code like:

```
job-a:
    outputs:
      comment: ${{ steps.store-comment.outputs.comment }}
    steps:
    - name: Check if QR already exists
      uses: peter-evans/find-comment@v2
      id: find-comment
      with:
        issue-number: ${{ github.event.number }}
        comment-author: "github-actions[bot]"
        body-includes: Preview Bundle

    - name: Store find-comment output
      id: store-comment
      run: echo "comment=${{ steps.find-comment.outputs.comment-id }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```